# List of Mathematica glyphs

Tags: front-end, symbols

### Context

I am using *Mathematica* to create live documents - documents that are both interactive and show mathematical derivations. Now, I'm aware that there are certain symbols that are available via:

```
\[CapitalSigma]
```

or
    <kbd>esc</kbd>S<kbd>esc</kbd>

However, some of the symbols I want (`\in`: $\in$, `\subsetneq`: $\subsetneq$) do not belong in the greek letters. Is there a list of something similar to [this](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) but lists *Mathematica* symbols instead of $\LaTeX$ symbols?

Thanks!

Comment: I retitled it to "textual symbols" to avoid confusion with `Symbol`, though it might be better to use "special characters and symbols" instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The guide [Listing of Named Characters](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html) in Mma docs:

> Mathematica provides systemwide support for a large number of special characters. Each character has a name and a number of shortcut aliases. They are fully supported by the standard Mathematica fonts. For further information about named characters, including character interpretations and naming conventions, please see "Named Characters".

A few examples from the start of the list:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @user1311390, my pleasure.

Comment: +1, because there have been times I've looked for it before and couldn't find it when I needed it.

Comment: @rcollyer, thanks for the vote. It always takes me several clicks to locate them too :)

Answer (score 6):

You could try the Special Characters palette. You can hover over the symbol and see its name.

Answer (score 6):

I could not find this elsewhere, here is a way to generate the list programatically:

```
Select[{FromCharacterCode[#], 
     Last@StringSplit[ExportString[FromCharacterCode[#], "Package"]], 
      #} & /@ 
   Range[200] , (* 65536 for the full list takes like 20 minutes *)
   StringTake[#[[2]], 3] == "\"\\[" &] // TableForm
```

[image]

Edit: much faster..

```
StringCases[
 ExportString[{#, FromCharacterCode@#} & /@ Range[65536], "Package"],
  Shortest[ 
   "{" ~~ n : NumberString ~~ ", \"\[" ~~ s : __ ~~ "]\"}" ] :> 
       {ToExpression@n, s, FromCharacterCode@ToExpression@n}]
```

Comment: This takes `0.39` seconds on my machine: `Select[Table[{i, #, ToString[FullForm[#]]} &[
     FromCharacterCode[i]], {i, 65535}], 
   StringMatchQ[#[[3]], "\"\\[" ~~ __] &]; // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: Whoops! I didn't see your edit!