# How do I construct a "named character" programmatically?

Tags: string-manipulation, named-characters

Why am I getting the error

> Syntax::sntunc: Unicode longname  in the string is unterminated.

from the following?

```
astroSymbol[name_String] := ToString[ToExpression["\[" <> name <> "]"]] <> "" ;
```

Is there something I need to do to wrap the escape sequence to avoid this error?

Comment: You have to escape the slash: "\\\["

Comment: That's the answer. I'm surprised it works at all without the escape (it generates the expected string).

Comment: You can write an answer to your own question, now. :)

Comment: Related: [(7610)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7610/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include a backslash in a string, you need to escape it, like so:

```
"\\[" <> name <> "]"
```