# Inverse of CharacterName

Tags: string-manipulation, built-in-symbols, character-encoding, named-characters

Is there an inverse function to `CharacterName`? For example, `CharacterName["ε"]` gives `"CurlyEpsilon"`. I'm looking for a function to do the reverse, given `"CurlyEpsilon"`, output `"ε"`. The best I could come up with was `ToString[ToExpression[ "\[" <> # <> "]" ]]&`, but I feel there must be a better way.

Comment: marginally better I suppose from the docs, ``ToExpression["\"\\[" <> # <> "]\""] &``  (eliminating the `ToString` )

Comment: Slightly shorter: `Symbol["\[" <> # <> "]"] &`

Comment: at least closely related: [How do I construct a “named character” programmatically?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14581/5478)

Comment: @Kuba I closed the question as a duplicate of that seconds before you commented. :^)

Comment: You could create a look-up table using the code in [(102079)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102079/121) if you find that cleaner.

Comment: In versions 10.2-11.0.1, there is the following undocumented expression: ``System`Private`LookupCodeByName["CurlyEpsilon"] // FromCharacterCode``.

Answer (score -2):

Just put `FullForm` in front to go one way:

```
FullForm[ε]
```

(* \[Epsilon] *)

and `\[Epsilon]`

to go the other

(* ε *)

Comment: That's not what OP asks. The "better" way would be using `WolframLanguageData` or some kind of `Entity` to extract the symbol from its name.