How to Prevent Short Name Character from Auto Converting
The following code creates the short name character aliasdelimiter, then selects it and reads and tests it.
FrontEndTokenExecute["ShortNameDelimiter"];
SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], Previous, Character];
If[NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]] == "\[AliasDelimiter]",
 Print[1],
 Print[2]]

If you copy and paste this code into a notebook it prints 1, which is correct. :)
However, if you actually try typing this code into a notebook you run into a problem when you type \[AliasDelimiter].  It automatically switches to its character form and breaks my test.
Is there a way to prevent this from happening?  Basically I want a way to write a short name character without auto converting to the character, this way my test prints 1.

I don't really understand what your overall goal is. Anyhow, I think you are facing some perks of \[AliasDelimiter] in the front end. For example, look at this screenshot. The two lines look completely identical, but one of them gives a syntax error and the other one doesn't. The reason is that their box structures is different, and you have to somehow fiddle with typing to get from one form to another. Anyhow, the easiest solution would be to use FromCharacterCode[63332].

or use this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20279/5478

@kuba that’s what I’m looking for.  I’ll mark this as a duplicate.
