# How could get all escape characters in Mathematica?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, java

I am evaluating expression by using `KernelLink`.

But the kernel will be suspended endless when meets a invalid escape character. `a\abc`, `\[badEscape]` for example.

So I have to filter all the invalid escape characters programmingly.

Is there a way to get all valid escape characters in *Mathematica*? `\[Beta]`,`\[Alpha]` and so forth.

### This is possibly caused by not all packets are read off properly

I will show the Mathematica code bellowd that you could test easily.

I'm using `EnterTextPacket` function(which communicates through WSTP) to talk with KernelLink. You could find refercence [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EnterTextPacket.html?q=EnterTextPacket)

**The first** case evaluates `10!`, and works well

```
link = LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -wstp"]
LinkRead[link]
LinkWrite[link, EnterTextPacket["10!"]]
LinkRead[link]
LinkRead[link]
LinkRead[link](*the last package*)
LinkClose[link]
```

[image: works well]

we could see the last `LinkRead[link]` returned `In[2]:=`  indicates all packages read off.

**The next** case evaluates `\[BadEscape]` causes packages returned with endless. `LinkRead[link]` returned `Syntax Err` continuously.

```
link = LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -wstp"]
LinkRead[link]
LinkWrite[link, EnterTextPacket["\[BadEscape]"]]
LinkRead[link]
LinkRead[link]
LinkRead[link]
....
(*endless*)
```

[image]
[image]

So I think this must be the problem. Does this make sense ?

Comment: Do you mean J/Link?  Can you give a specific example that causes the kernel to hang?  It shouldn't hang.  Maybe you are just not reading off all the packets (error messages) from the link ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of Mathematica glyphs](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7610/list-of-mathematica-glyphs)

Comment: The reason why I wouldn't mark it as duplicate is that very likely the cause of the problem is not the invalid named character.  Instead the link might be blocking because not all packets are read off properly.  Thus the solution is *not* to filter these named characters.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for reply. Yes, it's J/Link, called by java. I will give you the specified code tommorow since I am out off office.

Comment: I am not familiar with J/Link itself, but the sequence of calls should be similar to the C interface of MathLink ... so maybe I can comment

Comment: @Szabolcs I edited the question with code. Please take a look, thanks

Comment: Very strange.  I don't know what is going on.  Other syntax errors that appear at position 0, such as from `*2`, do not cause an infinite number of packets.  I wonder if this is a bug.  Minor note:  it should be `"\\[BadEscape]"`, with a double `"\\"` that encodes a single `\` in a string. But that's not the cause of the problem.  Just about any input starting with a backslash triggers this.

Comment: @Szabolcs No idea if it's a bug, so just leave this to the expert or the developer. I am going to filter escapes programmingly.

Comment: What are you programming exactly?  `EvaluatePacket` with `ToExpression` and maybe `SyntaxQ` might be a good workaround ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34539/discussion-between-michael-and-szabolcs).

Comment: Could you please report this problem to Wolfram and let us know what they said?  I am curious.  Looks like a bug.

Comment: @Szabolcs Could you please provide a way that I can get touch with Wolfram ? Or do you mean http://community.wolfram.com/ ?

Comment: @Michael The contact options are shown here: http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?source=nav You can also email `support@wolfram.com`.

Comment: This bothers me to no end so I reported it after all. CASE:3523179.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks. I was a little busy. could you please message me here when you get the result ?

Comment: @Szabolcs Just let you known, Wolfram has confirmed this's a native defect. I just got the feedback email. This will be fixed in next release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The help documentation has a section called Listing of Named Characters.  One way to get to it is to hit the F1 key and then paste the following into the documentation window:

```
guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters
```

To generate a list programmatically, code

```
codes = Table[ToString[
    FromCharacterCode[u],
    InputForm,
    CharacterEncoding -> "PrintableASCII"],
   {u, 0, 65535}];
lnames = Flatten@StringCases[codes, "\\[" ~~ __ ~~ "]" ];
```

In MMA 10.3, that should generate a list of 1005 long names.  It may or may not match the named character list in the documentation.