# Weird behavior of ℏ (\[HBar]) symbol on TensorExpand

Tags: tensors, symbols, dot

I was trying to implement some tools to do commutators on quantum mechanics, just for fun. Then I noted a peculiarity:

```
In[1]  := TensorExpand[(-ℏ).a]
Out[1] := ℏ (-1).a
```

Which is not typical of any `Symbol`:

```
In[1]  := TensorExpand[(-b).a]
Out[1] := -b.a
```

I did a little test based on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104460) to obtain a fair amount of special symbols:

```
codes = Table[
   ToString[FromCharacterCode[u], InputForm, 
    CharacterEncoding -> "Symbol"], {u, 0, 65535}];

lnames = Flatten@StringCases[codes, "\\[" ~~ __ ~~ "]"];

symbols = Quiet[ToExpression[lnames]] /. {$Failed | Null -> Nothing};
```

And then which symbols came out of `Dot` with `TensorExpand`:

```
In[5]  := Cases[Map[TensorExpand[(-#).a] &, symbols], Except[Times[-1, _]]]
Out[5] := {ℏ (-1).a, E (-1).a, (-I).a, (-I).a}
```

I get that `TensorExpand` cannot figure out the dot product with `-I`, and that it takes away the `E`, as it has certain algebraic properties hard coded into it, but to me it seems weird that despite having different properties:

```
In[6]  := {Head[E], NumericQ[E]}
Out[6] := {Symbol, True}
In[7]  := {Head[ℏ], NumericQ[ℏ]}
Out[7] := {Symbol, False}
```

They are treated as the same by this `TensorExpand` thing.

Could you give me an insight on this special behaviour of `ℏ`?

Comment: It denotes a physical quantity with physical units. Mathematica understands this difference.

Comment: Just gotta ask: have you added any definitions to `\[Hbar]` at any point? Also which version are you using? I don't get that behavior on 12.1 & nothing in the `DownValues` seems problematic